# R get file path from file names

Tags: r

I am trying to match File_names with File_paths.
Skip NA values but don’t remove them.
If a line has two matches, return both separated by a semi colon
Save the result as File_paths.

File_paths <- c(“C:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg”, “C:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg”, “C:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg”, “C:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg”, “C:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg”, “C:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg”)

File_names <- c(“b~cat”, “b~dog”, “NA”, “b~duck”, “b~goat; b~horse”, “NA”, “b~cow”

Desired output
dd <-

```
File_name       File_path       
b~cat           c:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg
b~dog           c:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg  
NA              NA                                        
b~duck          c:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg 
b~goat; b~horse c:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg; c:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg
NA              NA                         
b~cow           c:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg
```

Comment: You might be looking for `value=TRUE` in `grep`. Try `grep(pattern='fa', x=c('do', 're', 'mi', 'fa', 'so', 'la'), value=TRUE)`.

Comment: Please add a small reproducible example of input and desired output.

Comment: If you're using the stringr package `str_replace_all()`  might do what you want. Though hard to say without code :D

Comment: what do you mean by *switch output*?

Comment: you need to switch `“` to `"` for it to be correct R code

Comment: Your question is incomplete still. Do you have `File_names` or are you looking for the `file_names`??

Comment: @onyambu yes it has been updated

Answer (score 5):

```
stack(sapply(sub("; *", '|', File_names), \(x)paste0(grep(x,File_paths, value = TRUE), collapse = '; ')))[2:1]
             ind                                                    values
1          b~cat                                C:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg
2          b~dog                                C:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg
3             NA                                                          
4         b~duck                               C:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg
5 b~goat|b~horse C:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg; C:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg
6             NA                                                          
7          b~cow                                C:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg
```

Comment: Very clever to replace `; *` with `|`! Nice solution :)

Comment: @onyambu thank you so much! would you be able to help in adding the hyperlink to the path? I have tried class(File_Paths) <- "hyperlinks" but once I run it the hyperlinks are non existent in the table and excel document I export it to

Answer (score 3):

```
File_paths <- c("C:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg", "C:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg", "C:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg", "C:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg", "C:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg", "C:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg")
File_names <- c("b~cat", "b~dog", "NA", "b~duck", "b~goat; b~horse", "NA", "b~cow")


library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(files = File_names) |>
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    # fix NAs
    files = ifelse(files == "NA", NA, files)
  ) |>
  separate_rows(files, sep = "; ") |>
  mutate(
    path = ifelse(!is.na(files), lapply(files, grep, x = File_paths, value = TRUE), NA_character_),
    path = unlist(path)
  ) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  summarize(across(everything(), paste, collapse = "; "))
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
#      id files           path                                                     
#   <int> <chr>           <chr>                                                    
# 1     1 b~cat           C:/temp/1245~b~cat~v4.jpeg                               
# 2     2 b~dog           C:/temp/1245~b~dog~v4.jpeg                               
# 3     3 NA              NA                                                       
# 4     4 b~duck          C:/temp/1245~b~duck~v4.jpeg                              
# 5     5 b~goat; b~horse C:/temp/1245~b~goat~v4.jpeg; C:/temp/1245~b~horse~v4.jpeg
# 6     6 NA              NA                                                       
# 7     7 b~cow           C:/temp/1245~b~cow~v4.jpeg
```